Bizzare definite integral
Can anyone help me with the improper integral below:
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1}} \cos(x) \cos(y) \cos(z) \, dx \, dy \, dz
$$
The exact value is not important, just want to know if this integral is zero or not. I am quite sure that this integral is convergent. And I have tried to evaluate it by integrating numerically, but it is so computationally intensive such that the result I got is inconclusive.
I highly appreciate your help!

What is the analogous result if there are only two variables?
